# How to plot a document topic distribution in structural topic modeling R-package?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, topic-modeling

If I am using python Sklearn for LDA topic modeling, I can use the transform function to get a "document topic distribution" of the LDA-results like here:

```
document_topic_distribution = lda_model.transform(document_term_matrix)
```

Now I tried also the R structural topic models (stm) package and i want get the same. Is there any function in the stm package, which can produce the same thing (document topic distribution)?
I have the stm-object created as follows:

```
stm_model <- stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab,
                       K = number_of_topics, data = out$meta, 
                       max.em.its = 75, init.type = "Spectral" )
```

But i didn't find out how I can get the desired distribution out of this object. The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stm) didn't really help me aswell.

Comment: the `theta` slot in the resulting stm results object is what you want. From the documentation `theta` is a matrix of documents _x_ topics with per document topic proportions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As emilliman5 pointed out, your `stm_model` provides access to the underlying parameters of the model, as is shown [in the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stm/versions/1.3.3/topics/stm).

Indeed, the `theta` parameter is a

> Number of Documents by Number of Topics matrix of topic proportions.

This requires some linguistical parsing: it is an `N_DOCS` by `N_TOPICS` matrix, i.e. it has `N_DOCS` rows, one per document, and `N_TOPICS` columns, one per topic. The values are the topic proportions, i.e. if `stm_model[1, ] == c(.3, .2, .5)`, that means Document 1 is 30% Topic 1, 20% Topic 2 and 50% Topic 3.

To find out what topic dominates a document, you have to find the (column!) index of the maximum value, which can be retrieved e.g. by calling `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, which basically says "do this row-wise"; `which.max` simply returns the index of the maximum value:

```
apply(stm_model$theta, MARGIN=1, FUN=which.max)
```