# Predicting topics for each document in the data using structural topic modeling (STM)

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I've been trying to run structural topic modeling (STM package in R) to predict topics for documents. I followed all the steps mentioned in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/vignettes/stmVignette.pdf, but I can't find any object that contains documents-topics so I can export to csv.

Is there a way that I can export a document-topic dataframe to a csv file from stm results? I am looking for that dataframe.

Thanks

```
    # ESTIMATION
    poliblogPrevfit = stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab, K=30, prevalence = ~event+Covid,
                          max.em.its = 75, data=out$meta, init.type = "Spectral")
    
    storage = searchK(docs, vocab, K=c(5,6,7,8,9), prevalence = ~s(eventdiff), data = meta)
    plot(storage)
    
    
    # EVALUATION: model selection and search
    ## stm model: topic number = 15 (based on searchK result)
    poliblogPrevfit = stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab, K=15, prevalence = ~event,
                          max.em.its = 75, data=out$meta, init.type = "Spectral")
    
 
    poliblogSelect = selectModel(out$documents, out$vocab, K=15, prevalence =~event, max.em.its = 75,
                                 data=out$meta, runs=20, seed=111)
    
    plotModels(poliblogSelect, pch = c(1,2,3,4), legend.position="bottomright")
    
    selectModel = poliblogSelect$runout[[1]]
    
    labelTopics(poliblogPrevfit, c(1:7)) 
    sageLabels(poliblogPrevfit,10)
    
    shortdoc <- substr(out$meta$documents, 1, 200)
    thought <- findThoughts(poliblogPrevfit, texts=out$data$text, topics=1, n=10)
```

Comment: 1) The link you posted was broken; 2) I don't understand the question, are you looking for a way to export an object output by what function? I suggest that you take a look at `help("saveRDS")`, objects of class `"stm"` are not dataframes nor coercible to one.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the link. I don't even know what object contains document-topic matrix or what command gives me that. It's very easy to do in LDA in Python. I just use (lda_model.fit_transform(data_vectorized) to get document-topic matrix. But I can't figure out how to do it in STM. My main question is where (in what object, whatever its format is) STM stores the document-topic matrix or if there is any specific command/function that yields that result. Thanks

Comment: See if [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948857/how-to-plot-a-document-topic-distribution-in-structural-topic-modeling-r-package) can help.

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.